# How to split Chinese words and English words in a string using python with space?

Tags: python, string

I want to split "Coffee Hello 咖啡 咖啡"
into
"Coffee Hello" and "咖啡 咖啡" How should I do it? I used `isalpha` and `isspace` but it is not working. It is splitting into "Coffee Hello 咖啡 咖啡", "" instead.I found a simple fix by using regexp checking the index of first alphabet and splitting by that index.

Comment: so if a sentence has `Coffee 咖啡 咖啡 Hello` do u want it to be `['Coffee', '咖啡', '咖啡', 'Hello']`?

Comment: Well, because `isalpha()`is true for any "word" characters. The proper solution really defines on how you define "English" and "Chinese" in more detail. Should *'naïveté'* still count as a single English (loan) word?

Comment: Also, how exactly did you end up with the result you report? Please [edit] to show your current code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to consider is plain english characters you can use a combination of lookahead and look behind:

```
re.split("(?<=[a-zA-Z])\s*(?=[^a-zA-Z]*$)","Coffee Hello 咖啡 咖啡" )
```

this splits by any number of spaces (`\s*`) but only if the character before is from the English alphabet (`(?<=[a-zA-Z])` = `(?<=)`: lookbehind; `[a-zA-Z]`: english characters) and if everything  that follows is not from the English alphabet  (`(?=[^a-zA-Z]*$)` = `(?=)`: lookahead; `[^a-zA-Z]*$`: not Englisch characters to the end of the line)

Comment: Ö won't be counted here, but that's not chinese

Comment: It's also not English which was a caveat stated in the answer

Comment: This won't work when Chinese words precede English words, e.g. `"咖啡 咖啡 Coffee Hello"`.

Answer (score 2):

Regex would do:

```
>>> import re
>>> string = "Coffee Hello 咖啡 咖啡"
>>> re.split("(?<=[A-Za-z+])\s*(?=[\u4e00-\u9fa5+])", string)
['Coffee Hello', '咖啡 咖啡']
>>>
```

Comment: But it will not split "CoffeeHello咖啡咖啡" into "CoffeeHello" and "咖啡咖啡"

Comment: Then use a different regex: `)\s*(`

Comment: @HarshdeepKanhai Edited my answer with another regex!

Comment: @HarshdeepKanhai Even your title says "with space". If your strings don't in general look like English followed by a space followed by Chinese, you should make that clear and give us a proper specification.

Comment: @HarshdeepKanhai Luts's answer is **not** what you want, it doesn't detect chinese characters...!

Answer (score 2):

@Lutz's and @U12-Forward's answers only work when English words precede Chinese words.

A better-rounded approach that works regardless of the order of English and Chinese words would be to use `re.findall` with an alternation pattern instead:

```
re.findall(r'[a-z]+(?:\s+[a-z]+)*|[\u4e00-\u9fa5]+(?:\s+[\u4e00-\u9fa5]+)*', string, re.I)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/PzO3IL@oRKEolaugKDOvRKMoVS8tMy8lMSdHo0g9OlG3KlZbw94qplgbwtbUqomOKTVJNTDQjSm1TEs0hUujiWpqqesoKDnnp6Wlpip4pObk5Cs8nTTt6dSFUEpJB2innqemJk3sRbFKAdkVcHv//wcA)